# The program works in browser's console totally fine but the code does not redirect to the required html page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, href, window.location

I am trying to make a page where a student/ admin would select a radio button and click next button. After doing this the page will b redirected to the page for respective users. I ran this code in chrome console it worked fine but when I tried running it on chrome it doesn't do anything. The program runs fine for the third case, the first two doesn't work on chrome.

```js
function navigate() {
  var choice = document.forms[0];
  if (choice[0].checked === true) {
    window.location.href = "student.html";
  } else if (choice[1].checked === true) {
    window.location.href = "admin.html";
  } else {
    alert("Select a valid choice!!!");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome to SMS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to SMS (Student Management System)</h1>
  <form>
    <h3> Tell us who you are:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="student">Student
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="admin">Admin<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" onclick="navigate()">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? I have tried to run your example in a jsfiddle and it works as you describe it should: https://jsfiddle.net/8ovnuw47/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a `submit` button inside a `<form>`!

In this case, when you click your button, the first thing the browser does is submitting your form to the specified action. In your example, while there is no attribut `action` in the `<form>` the browser will simply reload the page.

The solution is to :

```
// change
<input type="submit" value="Next" onclick="navigate()">
// with
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="navigate()">
```

Or if you want to keep the `submit` button, you can `prevent` the `submit event` :

```
// HTML
<input type="submit" value="Next" onclick="navigate(event)">
// JS
function navigate(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Your other code goes here
}
```